# Putting variable in string (arduino)

Tags: c++, string, arduino, arduino-uno

I want to write a function for my arduino project, but I have some issues.

```
char telephone_number = 111232113;
Serial.println("AT+CMGS=\"telephone_number\"\r");
```

Console is showing me `AT+CMGS="telephone_number"` but instead of this I want `AT+CMGS="111232113"` to be shown.

Is it even possible in this form? I'm new in programming and I don't know how to manage that.

Comment: This is a classic [question for google](https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+combine+string+and+variable).  Awesome that you are a new programmer!  Keep going.  You and google will become *very* good friends.  Its knows more than anyone on Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: Can this help?
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=649730.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `String`.  Temptingly easy to use, but you will eventually be sorry.  :-(  They are slower, use more RAM, and add 1.6k to your program size.  Just stick with plain old C strings, also known as `char` arrays.

You can break your print statement up into three parts:

```
char telephone_number[] = "111232113";
Serial.print( "AT+CMGS=\"" );
Serial.print( telephone_number );
Serial.println( "\"\r" );
```

You can save even more RAM space by using the `F` macro around the print of double-quoted strings:

```
char telephone_number[] = "111232113";
Serial.print( F("AT+CMGS=\"") );   // Saves 10 bytes of RAM
Serial.print( telephone_number );
Serial.println( F("\"\r") );       // Saves 3 bytes of RAM
```

Any place you print a double-quoted string like that, just wrap it with the `F` macro.

BTW, I assume the telephone number(s) is not a constant, so you need to keep it in RAM, as the `char` array shown here.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there!

There are two points you need to fix:

1. `char telephone_number = 111232113;`. The type `char` is usually used to keep a single character. In Arduino, you can to use the class [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/String) to represent multiple characters.
2. In order to concatenate the value of a string variable with another string you need to use the operator `+`. See [String Addition Operator](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAdditionOperator).

Here is the corrected code:

```
String telephone_number = "111232113";
Serial.println("AT+CMGS=\"" + telephone_number + "\"\r");
```